# Can a US citizen leave the airport briefly while transiting through Zurich?

Tags: visas, schengen, us-citizens, switzerland

I am a US citizen with a US passport, traveling to Mumbai through Zurich. Indian travel visas have already been obtained. The return flight has an extended layover for a few hours, and my wife and I would like to exit the airport and visit Zurich briefly. Do we need Swiss visas to do so? If so, what kind of visa would we need?

Comment: Yes - you can go outside, I've done it a month ago while traveling from Russia. You need tram # 10 to get to the center.

Answer (score 17):

A visa is not required for a US citizen [to enter Switzerland](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/country/switzerland-and-liechtenstein.html) (who plans to stay for less than 90 days).

Comment: (... and who has been in any of the Schengen countries on less than 90 of the preceding 180 days).

Comment: @HenningMakholm exactly.